# Retrieving intranet website content with requests.get/urllibopen not working

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to **scrape** some data from an intranet website. I used

```
requests.get()
```

as well as

```
urllib2.request.urlopen()
```

to grab the content from the website and both of them get some content, it's just not what I am looking for. I looked at the source of the page in chrome and I compared it with the content grabbed by requests.get () and urlopen and they don't match.

I am getting this for a result

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html _manifest="receiver.appcache">
 <head>
  <meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title class="_ctxstxt_NetscalerAAA">
   NetScaler AAA
  </title>
  <link href="receiver/images/common/icon_vpn.ico" rel="ICON" sizes="16x16 32x32 48x48 64x64" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"/>
  <link href="receiver/images/common/icon_vpn.ico" rel="SHORTCUT ICON" sizes="16x16 32x32 48x48 64x64" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"/>
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport"/>
  <!-- Allow app to use the full screen if it is launched from a web clip on the springboard -->
  <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable"/>
  <meta content="black" name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style"/>
  <!-- This script block is to get the HTML5 elements to display correctly in older versions of IE that do not support them -->
  <script>
   document.createElement('header');
        document.createElement('nav');
        document.createElement('section');
```

I used this code to get the content. It works but the content is not really the content of the website I am looking at

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

nexflow = requests.get('https://apps.sfwmd.gov/flowgui/search.do?m\
                       ethod=structureDetails&type=G&offsetDatum=OTHER&st\
                       ation=S79_S', verify = False)
```

I am expecting something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
 
 
 
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var contextPath = '/flowgui'
 </script>

  <title>NEXFLOW - Next Generation Flow Program</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="-1">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">    
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection, print" href="/css/new.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
        var basePath = "/base";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scriptsFlow.js"> </script>
    

  <title>
   Location/Structure Details
  </title>
 </head>
 <body><div id="header">
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/new.css"/>
<div class=header>
   <div class="heading">
      <table width="100%">
      <tr><td height="19px"></td> </tr>
      <tr><td align="center" style="color:white;" width="90%">
         <i>NEXFLOW</i></br>Next Generation Flow Program
      </td></tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
  </div><!-- end header --><div id="topNav">
```

This is only happening to the intranet website, the code works fine in other websites. Is there anything I can add to adjust for the intranet?

Answer (score 0):

This could be to the page being dynamic i.e it makes use of javascript to fetch data.

I would suggest you use selenium to get the whole source code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=yourdriver)
nexflow ='''https://apps.sfwmd.gov/flowgui/search.do?m\
                   ethod=structureDetails&type=G&offsetDatum=OTHER&st\
                   ation=S79_S'''
driver.get(nexflow)
html = driver.page_source
```

and **html** is the source code